# How to get the device token from laravel to send push notification?

Tags: android, ios, laravel, token

I'm new to laravel and I want to send a push notification to my android and ios device. I know how to send push notification but I don't know how to  get the device token.

Comment: You should add more context to this question. What have you tried, exactly? Could you show us the PHP code and/or the Android code?

Comment: What are you using to send push notification ?

Answer (score 0):

I use :"davibennun/laravel-push-notification" https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification to send pushnotification

Answer (score 0):

In your class that extends FirebaseMessagingService Service in onNewToken method send the new token to the back-end and store it in database and whenever you wan't to send notification through backend(laravel) use that token...

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    ...
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    super.onNewToken(token);
    sendTokenToServer(token);
}
private void sendTokenToServer(String token) {
    //Send it to server using retrofit or any other lib that you're familiar with
}
}
```